# move tfs 2015 project from one collection to another TFS 2015 update 3

Tags: tfs-2015

I am the admin of TFS 2015 Upgrade 3. I would like to create a new collection and move some of the existing team projects from an existing collection to this new one using generic MS tools (not third party). Is this feature available, and if so can you post a hyperlink for steps?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Genearlly we can not move projects from one collection to another.

However you can split a team project collection. Simply say you can clone from the existing colleciton, then delete other unneeded projects from the cloned colleciton.

Follw the steps mentioned in this article to do that:
[Split a team project collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/split-team-project-collection)